# Xamarin Android Mainactivity code is never reached

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I´m new to Xamarin and I tried to build the following program:

```
private TextView txtShow;
int counter = 0;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainPage);

    Button btnShowText = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShowText);
    txtShow = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtShow);
    btnShowText.Click += BtnShowText_Click;
}

private void BtnShowText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtShow.Text = "This is your " + counter++ + ". Click!!";
}
```

But the problem is, that when I debug, this code is never reached.

The result of clicking the button is, that the button text is changing to "2 clicks", "3 clicks", ....

I think the button still uses this code, which is from the blank app project example, although I changed the button Id. How can this happen?

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
```

Comment: Do a `Clean All` and `Build All` on your solution and debug your app again . Delete the output `bin` and `obj` directories if still having a problem and perform a `Build All` again.

Comment: Does execution reach OnCreate Method while debugging ?

Comment: I think this must be a bug because after creating a new project, it works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a `TextView` to a `EditText`:

This line here:

```
private TextView txtShow;
```

And here:

```
txtShow = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtShow);
```

Change it to Either a `TextView` or `EditView` depending on your needs, or what is in the xaml.